# Multiple src for img class="cover-image" using DomDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am using a script to get src of a `<img>` with class="cover-image"

The webpage is of a Google Playstore page.

Here's the script:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.igg.castleclash');
libxml_clear_errors();
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$image_src = $xp->query("//img[@class='cover-image']/@src");
foreach($image_src as $attr) {
    echo $attr->value. "<br/>";
}
```

Issue is, there's only one `<img>` tag with class name cover-image, but I am still getting 15 src values.

Comment: this is a question earlier, if you try to observe the markup it has indeed multiple results. use your `ctrl+f` in your dom inspector of browser to check. you can also just get the first occurence of it

Comment: then how can i get the first occurence of the tag??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to just get the first one, then you can add this on the xpath query:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.igg.castleclash');
libxml_clear_errors();
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$image_src = $xp->evaluate("string(//img[@class='cover-image'][1]/@src)");
echo $image_src;

echo "<img src='$image_src' alt='' />";
```

Also, if you want that cover image that's on the topmost portion of the site (near the header part), you could just point it directly to it:

```
$image_src = $xp->evaluate("
    string(
        //div[@class='details-info']
        /div[@class='cover-container']
        /img[@class='cover-image']/@src
    )
"); // much more specific
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there should be only 1 tag? I see 15 tags with this class in html code.